# Scope long selectors for use with sibling slectors

Tags: css

I have the css selector:

```css
div#panel section.event p.follower-new + div#panel section.event p.viewer {
}
```

However the browser does not evaluate the *adjacent sibling selector* between

`div#panel section.event p.follower-new`

and

`div#panel section.event p.viewer`

Instead I think it is evaluating `p.follower-new` and `div#panel`.

Is there any way to explicitly scope the selector so that the *adjacent sibling selector* works as expected?

**Note:** `p.follower-new + p.viewer` works as expect, however, I would ideally like to be able to limit the scope with `div#panel section.event`.

I have tried introducing the child selector and this did not work.

```css
div#panel > section.event > p.follower-new + div#panel > section.event > p.viewer {
}
```

Which does not make sense to me since I would expect `>` to have a higher order of operation than `+`.

Answer (score 1):

As I was asking the question the answer came to me. The solution is to include the scope

`div#panel section.event`

Only on the left hand side of the *adjacent sibling selector*. i.e.

```css
div#panel section.event p.follower-new + p.viewer {
}
```

Since only the first term needs to define the full scope. The second term is already assumed, as it is a sibling, to be within that scope.